# Entity Framework Filter the Ids that do not match any records in a given table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework (in a single query) how could I pass a list of Ids and filter the ones that don't have any matching records in the table? (retrieve the Ids which do not have any records out of the passed Id list)

For example in a scenario where Company has multiple Assets, I could do something like this to check if a particular company has no Assets (when receive false). This is ok when we want to just check one record.

```
await _dbContext.Assets.AnyAsync(a => a.CompanyId == companyId);
```

Just trying to filter from a given list. For example, let's say, the Assets table has records for companyId ***100*** and ***102***. If I do SQL "IN" with the following list, just trying to get Ids ***101*** and ***103*** which do not have any records in the Assets table?

```
List<int> companyIds = new List<int> { 100, 101, 102, 103 };

await _dbContext.Assets.Include(a => a.Company)
            .Where(a => !companyIds.Contains(a.Company.CompanyId))
            .Select(a => a.Company).ToListAsync()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you need top down query for such task rather than bottom up. Not only the bottom up query has problem implementing the desired filtering criteria, but also produces duplicates in the result set since you are querying the many side and then selecting the one side.

So, if you want to get companies with Ids from the list which have no assets, then do exactly that, e.g.

```cs
List<int> companyIds = new List<int> { 100, 101, 102, 103 };

var query = _dbContext.Companies
    .Where(c => companyIds.Contains(c.CompanyId))
        && !c.Assets.Any());
```

It's quite simple, logical and easy to understand the goal. If you need just the ids, then simply add `.Select(c => c.CompanyId)` at the end of the query.

The only assumption here is that you have inverse collection navigation property, which in general you should, in order to be able to write such queries. If you don't then you can do it the old school / pure LINQ way by replacing `!c.Assets.Any()` with something like

```cs
!_dbContext.Assets.Any(a => a.CompanyId == c.CompanyId)
```

Answer (score 1):

First filter the list of companies based on company Ids passed in the list.
then,

```
Where(c => !_dbContext.Assets.Any(a => a.CompanyId == c.CompanyId))
```

Using this, we ensure that we are only selecting the companies that do not have any matching record in Assets table.

Comment: Not exactly clear wat u mean.